# Android ActionBar Logo and Title

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm styling my action bar. I want to have an specific text color, an specific background color and I want it to have a logo on the left. I managed to modify the text and background with this code in styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.actionBar</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyTheme.actionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But when I add this code inside MyTheme.actionBar the logo appears but the text disappear.

```
<item name="logo">@mipmap/giftbox</item>
<item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT: Here is the Activity code:

```
public class Person extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_person);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_person, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: try to use [toolbar](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) instead of actionbar

Comment: Plase also post the code of Activity in which you want it

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html and specify logo in the menifest <application> tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Spannable text = new SpannableString(actionBar.getTitle());
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, text.length(),  Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
actionBar.setTitle(text);
```

Comment: And how do I get the actionBar?

Comment: ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); returns null

Comment: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); if you use this code means remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id",
                "android");
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
```

by this you can get the `ActionBar` title `TextView` for which you can set your own text, color, style

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom header view with the logo and textview and inflate it in your activity. With this approach also you can set whichever color you want to the background.

Like done in below code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.top_bar_light)));
            LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

            View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.headerbar_view, null);


            imgvwRefrsh = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.ximgvwrefresh);

            imgvwStreamoid = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.ximgvwStreamoid);
            getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(mCustomView);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```